# Is there watchpoints in radare2?

Tags: radare2, debuggers, breakpoint

Is there any way to put breakpoints in radare2 that trigger when an address is read/write?

In GDB those are call watchpoints ('rwatch' or 'awatch")

I got this from [radare2](https://www.radare.org/doc/html/Section20.6.3.html)

```
[0xB7F08810]> !dr?
Usage: !dr[type] [args]
  dr                   - show DR registers
  dr-                  - reset DR registers
  drr [addr]           - set a read watchpoint
  drw [addr]           - set a write watchpoint
  drx [addr]           - set an execution watchpoint
  dr[0-3][rwx] [addr]  - set a rwx wp at a certain DR reg
Use addr=0 to undefine a DR watchpoint
```

But I think that is old...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest r2 (`radare2 3.5.0-git`) uses `dbw` command to add watchpoints.

```
[0x00000000]> db?
Usage: db    # Breakpoints commands
...
| dbw <addr> <r/w/rw>       Add watchpoint
```